argocd-image-updater failing to connect aws ECR: Could not set registry endpoint credentials: invalid script output, must be single line with syntax
I am trying to setup a pull based deployment pipeline where argocd image updater reads updates to images in amazon elastic container registry. What have I done so far?

Installed image updater in the argocd namespace.
added registry.conf data to the image updater config map.

registries.conf: |
    registries:
      - name: Elastic Container Registry
        prefix: XXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com
        api_url: https://XXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com
        ping: yes
        default: true
        insecure: false
        credentials: ext:/scripts/ecr-login.sh
        credsexpire: 12h


Added script to fetch ecr credentials from AWS in the image updater authScript configMap.

ecr-login.sh: >
    #!/bin/sh

    aws ecr --region "XXXXXXXX" get-authorization-token --output text
    --query 'authorizationData[].authorizationToken' | base64 -di


Added annotations on the Argocd application to allow for image updater to know what to look for.

...
argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/write-back-method: git
argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/image-list: api=https://XXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com/api:latest,front=https://XXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com/front:latest
argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/update-strategy: digest
...

After all this I get this error on the argocd logs.
time="2024-07-12T21:54:13Z" level=info msg="argocd-image-updater v0.14.0+af844fe starting [loglevel:DEBUG, interval:2m0s, healthport:8080]"
time="2024-07-12T21:54:13Z" level=warning msg="commit message template at /app/config/commit.template does not exist, using default"
time="2024-07-12T21:54:13Z" level=debug msg="Successfully parsed commit message template"
time="2024-07-12T21:54:13Z" level=debug msg="rate limiting is disabled" prefix=XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com registry="https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com"
time="2024-07-12T21:54:13Z" level=debug msg="Setting default registry endpoint to XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com"
time="2024-07-12T21:54:13Z" level=debug msg="Previous default registry was docker.io"
time="2024-07-12T21:54:13Z" level=info msg="Loaded 1 registry configurations from /app/config/registries.conf"
time="2024-07-12T21:54:13Z" level=debug msg="Creating in-cluster Kubernetes client"
time="2024-07-12T21:54:13Z" level=info msg="ArgoCD configuration: [apiKind=kubernetes, server=argocd-server.argocd, auth_token=false, insecure=false, grpc_web=false, plaintext=false]"
time="2024-07-12T21:54:13Z" level=info msg="Starting health probe server TCP port=8080"
time="2024-07-12T21:54:13Z" level=info msg="Starting metrics server on TCP port=8081"
time="2024-07-12T21:54:13Z" level=info msg="Warming up image cache"
time="2024-07-12T21:54:13Z" level=debug msg="Processing application voting-microservice"
time="2024-07-12T21:54:13Z" level=debug msg="Considering this image for update" alias=vote application=voting-microservice image_name=vote image_tag=latest registry=XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com
time="2024-07-12T21:54:13Z" level=debug msg="Using version constraint 'latest' when looking for a new tag" alias=vote application=voting-microservice image_name=vote image_tag=latest registry=XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com
time="2024-07-12T21:54:13Z" level=info msg=/scripts/ecr-login.sh dir= execID=73f66
time="2024-07-12T21:54:15Z" level=error msg="Could not set registry endpoint credentials: invalid script output, must be single line with syntax <username>:<password>" alias=vote application=voting-microservice image_name=vote image_tag=latest registry=XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com
time="2024-07-12T21:54:15Z" level=debug msg="Considering this image for update" alias=result application=voting-microservice image_name=result image_tag=latest registry=XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com
time="2024-07-12T21:54:15Z" level=debug msg="Using version constraint 'latest' when looking for a new tag" alias=result application=voting-microservice image_name=result image_tag=latest registry=XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com
time="2024-07-12T21:54:15Z" level=info msg=/scripts/ecr-login.sh dir= execID=171dd
time="2024-07-12T21:54:16Z" level=error msg="Could not set registry endpoint credentials: invalid script output, must be single line with syntax <username>:<password>" alias=result application=voting-microservice image_name=result image_tag=latest registry=XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com
time="2024-07-12T21:54:16Z" level=info msg=/scripts/ecr-login.sh dir= execID=f0943
time="2024-07-12T21:54:16Z" level=debug msg="Considering this image for update" alias=worker application=voting-microservice image_name=worker image_tag=latest registry=XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com
time="2024-07-12T21:54:16Z" level=debug msg="Using version constraint 'latest' when looking for a new tag" alias=worker application=voting-microservice image_name=worker image_tag=latest registry=XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com
time="2024-07-12T21:54:18Z" level=error msg="Could not set registry endpoint credentials: invalid script output, must be single line with syntax <username>:<password>" alias=worker application=voting-microservice image_name=worker image_tag=latest registry=XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com
time="2024-07-12T21:54:18Z" level=info msg="Finished cache warm-up, pre-loaded 0 meta data entries from 2 registries"
time="2024-07-12T21:54:18Z" level=debug msg="Starting askpass server"
time="2024-07-12T21:54:18Z" level=info msg="Starting image update cycle, considering 1 annotated application(s) for update"
time="2024-07-12T21:54:18Z" level=debug msg="Processing application voting-microservice"
time="2024-07-12T21:54:18Z" level=info msg=/scripts/ecr-login.sh dir= execID=6dcbd
time="2024-07-12T21:54:18Z" level=debug msg="Considering this image for update" alias=vote application=voting-microservice image_name=vote image_tag=latest registry=XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com
time="2024-07-12T21:54:18Z" level=debug msg="Using version constraint 'latest' when looking for a new tag" alias=vote application=voting-microservice image_name=vote image_tag=latest registry=XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com
time="2024-07-12T21:54:20Z" level=error msg="Could not set registry endpoint credentials: invalid script output, must be single line with syntax <username>:<password>" alias=vote application=voting-microservice image_name=vote image_tag=latest registry=XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com
time="2024-07-12T21:54:20Z" level=info msg=/scripts/ecr-login.sh dir= execID=9e117
time="2024-07-12T21:54:20Z" level=debug msg="Considering this image for update" alias=result application=voting-microservice image_name=result image_tag=latest registry=XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com
time="2024-07-12T21:54:20Z" level=debug msg="Using version constraint 'latest' when looking for a new tag" alias=result application=voting-microservice image_name=result image_tag=latest registry=XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com
time="2024-07-12T21:54:21Z" level=debug msg="Considering this image for update" alias=worker application=voting-microservice image_name=worker image_tag=latest registry=XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com
time="2024-07-12T21:54:21Z" level=debug msg="Using version constraint 'latest' when looking for a new tag" alias=worker application=voting-microservice image_name=worker image_tag=latest registry=XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com
time="2024-07-12T21:54:21Z" level=error msg="Could not set registry endpoint credentials: invalid script output, must be single line with syntax <username>:<password>" alias=result application=voting-microservice image_name=result image_tag=latest registry=XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com
time="2024-07-12T21:54:21Z" level=info msg=/scripts/ecr-login.sh dir= execID=4b33d
time="2024-07-12T21:54:23Z" level=error msg="Could not set registry endpoint credentials: invalid script output, must be single line with syntax <username>:<password>" alias=worker application=voting-microservice image_name=worker image_tag=latest registry=XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.XXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com
time="2024-07-12T21:54:23Z" level=info msg="Processing results: applications=1 images_considered=3 images_skipped=0 images_updated=0 errors=3"

Please have any ideas on how I can get this to work.

I figured out the issue by accessing the pod to run the command and found that the command was failing because the pod didn't have aws credentials configured.
I fixed this by creating a secret with my AWS IAM user access key and secret. Then adding the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY environment variables to the argocd-image-updater deployment.yaml file
kubectl create secret generic aws-credentials --namespace argocd --from-literal=aws_access_key_id=[YOUR_USER_KEY]--from-literal=aws_secret_access_key="[YOUR_USER_SECRET_KEY]"

argocd-image-updater deployment.yaml
env:
  - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: aws-credentials
          key: aws_access_key_id
  - name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: aws-credentials
        key: aws_secret_access_key

